# How to find that particular View Section of ListView is Visible from 3 seconds

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scroll

i have 24 items in the listview where
 
`firstVisibleItem  = 0` 
`visibleItemCount = 6` 
`totalItemCount = 24`

so after it by scrolling i got
`firstVisibleItem = 16` 
`visibleItemCount = 6` 
`totalItemCount = 24`

after leaving that view whose `firstVisibleItem = 16` for some time , can we find that , my `ListView` section whose `firstVisibleItem = 16` is visible from `3 seconds` ( or any isntance of time ) .

**Edited** :

Basically , i want to create a listview where 24 images are present and i dont want to download whole 24 images , i just want to download those images which are present in that view which is present from 2-3 seconds .

Comment: You could create a custom listadapter and retrieve the right view (that contains the image) there. Retrieve the view that has the first visible position of the listview its children http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29. If you scroll your ListView, the ListView calls the getView method of its Adapter. You can override that method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29

Comment: Bram , i want to download images like google's play , google play App downloads only those images which are in the view from some time .